# Read Only File System with OfStream

Tags: c++11, ubuntu

I am trying to write to a file with ofstream in c++. It tells me that it is a "Read Only File System". I am able to make files outside of C++ -- i.e. other languages and with touch. Where path is "/home/<username/file.textpb" in my case it is "/home/andrew/file.textpb".

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::ofstream file("/home/andrew/file.textpb", std::ofstream::out);

  if (file.fail()) {
    std::cerr << "Write Error: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
  } else {
    file << "Some Text";

    file.close();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `path`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Edited with path. Sorry about that.

Comment: But `/home/andrew/` is a directory, not a file? Did you forget to add a file name after the final slash?

Comment: Good point! I left out the filename.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I added in the includes but what else is missing?

Comment: What's missing is the value of `path`. Chances are, it's not what you think it is. Have your program print it, so you can examine it.

Comment: I specified path in the description of this. I can specify in the code snippet too though.

Comment: The `main` is missing, meaning you didn't actually run the code you show us. If you add `main`, does it reproduce the error?

Comment: Yes it does. I have added in the main.

Comment: Try running the program under strace so you can see the exact system call that is failing, if one is fact failing with `EROFS`.

Comment: I think you are a magician....I ran it and voila my test suddenly started passing. THANK YOU!